# Django Password reset email never sends

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I'm using the built in Django password reset, and the 'password reset sent' page comes up, but the email never sends.  I have my email settings setup like this:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_email'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_password'
```

I included the following since I'm in development, but not totally sure if it's necessary:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
```

The console says:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Password reset on localhost:8000
From: myemail@gmail.com
To: anotheremail@hotmail.com
Date: Wed, 17 Feb 2016 04:53:17 -0000
Message-ID: <some_id@toms-macbook-air.local>
```

It looks like everything is happening that should, but the email never sends.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the dummy email backend used for testing only. Change the line

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

to

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#console-backend):

> **Console backend**
>
> Instead of sending out real emails the console backend just writes the
>   emails that would be sent to the standard output. By default, the
>   console backend writes to stdout. You can use a different stream-like
>   object by providing the stream keyword argument when constructing the
>   connection.